# How to limit the no. of top values when aggregating in a Function?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-functions

I am writing a function which just groupby a string property. For this purpose, I need to select `topValues()` as the aggregation type. However, I get all possible buckets, while I just need the first 10 ones. Is it possible to set the max. number of buckets to retrieve?

- `.topValues(10`) is not working. No configuration possibility available.
- I wrote a function to return 1000 values and then, keep just the first 10. This is however really unefficient.

Comment: Afaik it's indeed not possible, we'll drop an answer if it becomes available as a feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the topValues() aggregation does not support a pre-defined bucket count. Your approach of calculating the top 1000 and then post-filtering is the best option.

For others looking, here's a code snippet for reference:

```
const x = Object.search().myObjectType().groupBy(obj => obj.myStringProperty.topValues()).sum();
return {buckets: x.buckets.sort((x, y) => x.value - y.value).slice(0, 5)};
```

There is a feature request tracking an enhancement to add this configuration, though I would expect this to be more of a convenience rather than a performance improvement, since to calculate the top N buckets you roughly have to know the sizes of the other buckets (with some obvious room for optimization).